# Fill array with element N times

Tags: ruby

I want to fill an array with 1 element but 5 times.
What I got so far.

```
number = 1234
a = []

5.times { a << number }
puts a # => 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234
```

It works but this feels not the ruby way.
Can someone point me in the right direction to init an array with 5 times the same value?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

For immutable objects like Fixnums etc

```
Array.new(5, 1234) # Assigns the given instance to each item
# => [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234]
```

For Mutable objects like String Arrays

```
Array.new(5) { "Lorem" } # Calls block for each item
# => ["Lorem", "Lorem", "Lorem", "Lorem", "Lorem"]
```

Comment: This is the correct solution for immutable objects (Fixnums, Symbols, etc.) but for mutable objects (Strings, Arrays, etc.) you will get an Array with 5 pointers to the _same object_, which is probably not what you want. In that case use the block form `Array.new(5) { "foo" }`.

Answer (score 39):

This should work:

```
[1234] * 5
# => [1234, 1234, 1234, 1234, 1234]
```

Comment: This creates an unnecessary intermediate array that is immediately thrown away.

Answer (score 26):

Although the accepted answer is fine in the case of strings and other immutable objects, I think it's worth expanding on Max's comment about mutable objects.

The following will fill an array of elements with 3 individually instantiated hashes:

```
different_hashes = Array.new(3) { {} } # => [{}, {}, {}]
```

The following will fill an array of elements with a reference to the same hash 3 times:

```
same_hash = Array.new(3, {}) # => [{}, {}, {}]
```

If you modify the first element of different_hashes:

```
different_hashes.first[:hello] = "world"
```

Only the first element will be modified.

```
different_hashes # => [{ hello: "world" }, {}, {}]
```

On the other hand, if you modify the first element of same_hash, all three elements will be modified:

```
same_hash.first[:hello] = "world"
same_hash # => [{ hello: "world" }, { hello: "world" }, { hello: "world" }]
```

which is probably not the intended result.

Answer (score 4):

You can fill the array like this:

```
a = []
=> []

a.fill("_", 0..5) # Set given range to given instance
=> ["_", "_", "_", "_", "_"]

a.fill(0..5) { "-" } # Call block 5 times
```

Comment: This can be done in one step with `Array.new(6) {"_"}`. Also, I can't submit an edit this small, but the number of elements in the example output should be 6, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

these two methods will give an array of N values in ruby

Array.new(5, 2) => [2,2,2,2,2]

[2] * 5 => [2,2,2,2,2]